# simple hash table using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, hashtable

Is there a simple example for hash table implementation using boost lib. I read the following from the documentation

```
boost::hash<int,std::string> input;
```

I need to know if I can use hash table like:

```
input.add<key,instance_of_input_class>  //pseudo code
```

where Input class be:

```
class Input
{
    int id;
    std::String name;
}
```

Comment: I read the documentation, but I cant get any help how to add the Input  class into the hash table.

Comment: The `boost` or `std::unordered_map` template is an associative container (that is, it associates a key with a value). It is _implemented_ using a hash table. You don't show what your `Input` class is for or how you want to use it, so it's difficult to give a more detailed example than the existing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::hash` is not a hash table, it just calculates the hash value. See the Boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/hash/tutorial.html) for how to combine it with an unordered container and read the container's [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) on how to insert values.

Your comment declares a type `map`, not an instance of that type since you are using `typedef`.

Your post also suggests that maybe you don't even want/need `boost::hash`, try

```
std::unordered_map< int, std::string > my_map;
```

Of course, you can also use `boost::unordered_map` instead of `std::unordered_map` in case the latter doesn't work or you simply don't *want* to use it.

Now add a method to your class to allow access to the values:

```
class Input
{
  int id;
  std::string name; // note: lowercase string, not String

public:
  std::pair< int, std::string > values() const
  {
    return std::make_pair( id, name );
  }
};
```

And use it to insert instances of `Input` into the map:

```
Input my_input;
my_map.insert( my_input.values() );
```

Comment: ...This is what I read from the documentation                   typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;                          In this is map the instance of the hash table?

Comment: Oh, and in case this is something you are wondering about: Yes, `unordered_map` models a hash table.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is boost::unordered_map: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html

BTW, now unordered_map is included by C++11.